# How to trigger callback function in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

React and Redux experts.

I am new to React and Redux. My question is related to trigger callback (function) invocation when a Redux state is changed. I am stuck into this implementation. In my understanding, the presenter/view is updated via the props. Let me illustrate more in the following example.

`<ParentComponent>`
    `<Child1Component/>`
    `<Child2Component/>`
`</ParentComponent>`

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

    onChild1Click() {
        this.props.dispatch(setTool(Tools.CHILD1TOOL))
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                  <Child1Component onChild1Click={this.onChild1Click.bind(this)}/>
                  <Child2Component/>
             </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {state}
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(ParentComponent)
```

---

```
class Child1Component extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate() {
        // Question: How to get the Redux state here?
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.onPencilClick}>Pencil</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Suppose a button is present in the `Child1Component` and a `onclick` is attached to such button. In my understanding of Redux, an action should be attached to this `onclick` and it should be dispatched. Such state will be modified in the `ParentComponent` and trigger props update. Afterwards, the UI/Presenter of `Child1Component` will be updated via props instead of any callback of `Child1Component`.

Is it possible to trigger a callback in `Child1Component` when a state is altered? The reason I need to make such implementation is that a 3rd party library is adopted. It requires to trigger callback. Actually, the `onclick` can trigger the function (callback) directly. However, the state cannot be maintained.

Could any expert advise it, please? Thanks a million.

P.

Comment: Can you post some codes you have tried.  so we can understand the problem more :)

Comment: @shashith-darshana, thanks for your reply. I have added the code snippets here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thank you for the replies. I came up the solution eventually. Here it is.

```
// actions.js
export const SET_TOOL = 'SET_TOOL'

export const Tools = {
    CHILD1TOOL: 'child1tool',
    DEFAULT: 'default'
}

export function setTool(tool) {
    return {
        type: SET_TOOL,
        tool
    }
}
```

---

```
// reducers.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { SET_TOOL, Tools } from './actions'

const { DEFAULT } = Tools

function currentTool(state = DEFAULT, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_TOOL:
            return action.tool
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const myApp = combineReducers({
    currentTool
})

export default myApp
```

---

```
// ParentComponent.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Tools, setTool } from './actions'
import Child1Component from './Child1Component.jsx'

class ParentComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child1Component onChild1Click={this.props.onChild1Click'}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStatesToProps = state => {
    return {state}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onChild1Click: () => {
            dispatch(setTool(Tools.CHIDL1TOOL))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ParentComponent)
```

---

```
// Child1Component.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { Tools } from './actions'

class Child1Component extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate() {

        if (this.props.state.currentTool === Tools.CHILD1TOOL) {
            this.callbackHandleClick()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.props.onChild1Click}>Child 1 Button</button>
    }

    callbackHandleClick() {
        /* callback implementation */
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {state}
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Child1Component)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this is not directly related to redux. You can use the react life cycle methods for this purpose. In your case, I think you need the `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillUpdate` methods.

You can read more about life cycle methods here,
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

**Explanation**
First, make sure that you have connected the components to the Redux store using the [react-redux](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) bindings. Then, if you have correctly defined the `mapStateToProps` function, your child component will update whenever the state changes. Thus, whenever the component is updated, the `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` methods will be called.

**Example** in ES6 style

First, we'll bind the full redux state to the child component. *Note: Generally you would not bind the full state, but only a branch of it.*

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        // this will bind the redux state to the props of the child component
        reduxState: state 
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        // some action creators
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildComponent);
```

Then we can access the redux state from the child component.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount(nextProps, nextState) {
        // Do something here
        console.log(this.props.reduxState)
        // this.props.reduxState is accessible from anywhere in the component
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{/*Some jsx here*/}</div>
    }
}
```

**I strongly recommend you to read about redux usage with react section from redux docs and about smart-dumb component separation**

Comment: Thanks, @pubudu-dodangoda. I would like to know if it is possible to get the Redux state in the `componentWillUpdate` of `ChildComponent`.